# R pgirmess alternative for kruskalmc with Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

Tags: r, anova, kruskal-wallis

I'm trying to run the krushkalmc method after running kruskal.test as part of my analysis with the Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test.

However, I've run into difficulties trying to install the pgirmess package that contains krushkalmc.

## trying to install it from inside R:

```
install.packages("pgirmess")
   package ‘pgirmess’ is available as a source package but not as a binary
```

## so then I downloaded it and tried to install it manually:

```
install.packages("pgirmess", repos = NULL, type="source")
Warning: invalid package ‘pgirmess’
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pgirmess’ had non-zero exit status
```

## and here is my sessionInfo()

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.8     grid_3.1.2      
 [4] gtable_0.1.2     labeling_0.3     MASS_7.3-35     
 [7] munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10    
[10] Rcpp_0.11.4      reshape2_1.4.1   scales_0.2.4    
[13] stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.2
```

I've tried to determine if any other package has the kruskalmc but don't see any.

Do you have any recommendations on a replacement package that I can use that has a test to dive deeper into the results of Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test?

Is there a debug mode on an install.packages to see what might be the problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I am moving this question over to cross-validated (aka stats.stackoverflow.com) as it is probably a more suitable location for this question. I don't think I have the ability to actually close it here, though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am moving this question over to [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140641/is-dunn-test-a-suitable-alternative-to-kruskalmc-in-pgirmess-package) (aka stats.stackoverflow.com) as it is probably a more suitable location for this question. I don't think I have the ability to actually close it here, though. Thanks